# Why is the time reported by time() sometimes 1 second behind the seconds component of timespec_get() in C code?

Tags: c, time, posix, timespec

The following snippet of code:

```
struct timespec ts;
for (int x = 0; x < 100000000; x++) {
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    long cTime = (long) time(NULL);
    if (cTime != ts.tv_sec && ts.tv_nsec < 3000000) {
        printf("cTime: %ld\n", cTime);
        printf("ts.tv_sec: %ld\n", ts.tv_sec);
        printf("ts.tv_nsec: %ld\n", ts.tv_nsec);
    }
}
```

produces this output:

```
...
cTime: 1579268059
ts.tv_sec: 1579268060
ts.tv_nsec: 2527419
cTime: 1579268059
ts.tv_sec: 1579268060
ts.tv_nsec: 2534036
cTime: 1579268059
ts.tv_sec: 1579268060
ts.tv_nsec: 2540359
cTime: 1579268059
ts.tv_sec: 1579268060
ts.tv_nsec: 2547039
...
```

Why the discrepancy between `cTime` and `ts.tv_sec`? Note that the problem does not occur if the conditional is changed to `ts.tv_nsec >= 3000000`. The problem relies on nanoseconds being smaller than 3000000.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the operating system used, version of it, version of the C library used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Linux Debian 8, GCC 6.3.0.

Comment: What's `timespec_get()`? Is this C or C++? Looks like `std::timespec_get`. Please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It was added to C in C11. [Can reproduce online](https://tio.run/##VZFNb8IwDIbv/RUeEywVHXTHrbBLtQMa0MPKbVJVJS5ElKRqUsaE@O1d0owvH5rGefL6jU2f15S27SMXtGwYwkRpxuVo8@5dU5rv0GY8LjTsci7IXnLme0cPTChdN1SDhVSFFLQKQKNoFEzhGAbwEpo4RR1byBqIVTmYwzAyy8Sd2zDb4dAHp2rjLJmtUZOB1U1ni49slcZ@dIFKKdZAU4MaSWJ3vr1Hlqv5/AbjBRBHPUyNxZHeZwrpbTUbVW3MFaTXkW/QL9m36AVO/kbsFtWq40b98PWfvqiff4WtdH/7AMOpe3kE4zEkgiL8IChE0BsExhWtscoF/Q1M/olBybfuqJSyAi2h4IKrDSgpxZ0yLSXdZiIXUpWIFYnnSfyZLZJlkibLWRyAGcmgm08ArkfWwJdljSEwY8s15F3vbZncjhrwQFEpvkf3bG5azpq6W65OocKaS3Zxc/Lc99S2fw "C (gcc) – Try It Online").

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you for the reference, I couldn't see a `man` entry for `timespec_get` on my system so I jumped to conclusions. Makes sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is, that you (implicitly) use different system clocks. `timespec_get()` uses the *high resolution* system-wide realtime clock, while `time()` uses the *coarse* realtime clock.

Try to use

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, &ts);
```

instead of your `timespec_get()`, then the difference should vanish.

**Edit:**

This can be seen in the [Linux Kernel Source, vclock_gettime.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.37/source/arch/x86/entry/vdso/vclock_gettime.c)

Indeed the issue is a bit subtle to see here. The seconds-part of the structure members used by `CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE` and `CLOCK_REALTIME` contain identical values, but the *nanoseconds-part* is different; with `CLOCK_REALTIME` it can be larger than `1000000000` (which is one second). In this case, it is fixed up on the call:

```
ts->tv_sec += __iter_div_u64_rem(ns, NSEC_PER_SEC, &ns);
ts->tv_nsec = ns;
```

This correction is neither performed with `CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE`, nor with `time()`. This explains the difference between `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `time()`.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, or just an artifact of `time` being implemented with the (presumably) more performant but less accurate clock (on the theory that it's only got second granularity anyway, so who needs precision)? Lagging real time by a millisecond or so (online tests showed occasional lag of over a ms, but not much over) when you're only asking for second granularity isn't all that important I guess.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I added some more details

Comment: Not explicit documentation of intent, but that's enough detail for an up-vote.  :-) Funny that the clock can actually report more than a second's worth of additional nanoseconds.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I could not find a real documentation other than the source for that, which also means, that the behaviour might also change in detail without prior notice

Comment: @Ctx Thank you for the detailed answer! I will use timespec_get() rather than clock_gettime() that you advise, as timespec_get() is C11 rather than POSIX and doesn't require the setting of which clock to use. I had no idea different clocks were used, but given the choice, I don't see much point in using the coarse clock.